# Find the value of $a,b$ such that given limit exists

Tags: functions

> Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} =1$. If $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x(1+a\sin x)-b\sin x}{(f(x))^3}$ is finite, then find $a,b$

Let $f(x)=\sin x$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin x+ a\sin ^2x -b\sin x}{\sin^3 x}$$
$$\implies \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sin x(1-a) +a\sin ^2 x}{\sin^3 x}$$

Which leads to nowhere. If the assumption of $f(x)$ is wrong, then I don’t know what else to do. Can I get a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x(1+a\sin (x))-b\sin (x)}{(f(x))^3}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{x^3}\frac{x(1+a\sin (x))-b\sin (x)}{\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^3}$$

Now, consider Taylor series for
$$\frac{x(1+a\sin (x))-b\sin (x)}{x^3}$$

Comment: Without using taylor's series this can be done $\frac{x(1+a\sin x)-b\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{1-b\frac{\sin x}{x}+a\sin x}{x^2}$. Now if $ a\neq0 $ and $b\neq1$ then clearly the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @PNDas. For sure ! Your way is the simplest. Make an answer. Cheers -;)

Answer (score 1):

From @Claude's answer,
$$\frac{x(1+a\sin x)-b\sin x}{x^3}=\frac{1-b\frac{\sin x}{x}+a\sin x}{x^2}.$$

Now if $ a\neq0 $ or $b\neq1$ then clearly the limit doesn't exist .

But we didn't check that if $a=0,b=1$ then limit exists.

Hence suppose $a=0,b=1$ then $$L=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\frac{\sin x}{x}}{x^2}$$

Now you can use Taylor's series or L'Hospital's rule, using former we get,
$$L=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\frac{x^2}{3!}-\text{higher order terms}}{x^2}=\frac1 6$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The given limit exist and is finite if and only if $\frac {x(1+a \sin x)-b \sin x} {x^{3}}$ exist and is finite.  Using the expansion  of $\sin x$ as $x-\frac {x^{3}} {3!}+...$ we see that the limit exist if and only if $b=1$ and $a=0$.

More details: $\frac {1-b+ax} {x^{2}}$ is bounded. If $|1-b+ax| \leq Mx^{2}$ the letting $x \to 0$ we get $1-b=0$. And then we get $|a|\leq M|x|$ so we can letting $x \to 0$ in this to get $a=0$.